# how use order by clause in group by statement

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have two table `tbl_issue_log, tbl_magazine_issue`

```
tbl_issue_log
============

+----------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| issue_id | mag_id | log_id | operation |    updated_time     |
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| 2        | 1      | 1      | 1         | 2014-01-30 21:29:44 |
| 3        | 4      | 1      | 1         | 2015-01-30 21:29:44 |
| 2        | 1      | 1      | 3         | 2015-01-31 21:29:44 |
+----------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
```

```
tbl_magazine_issue
=================
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------+
| ISSUE_ID | ISSUE_NAME  | MAGAZINE_ID | COVER_PAGE_THUMB | FROM_DATE  |  TO_DATE   | issue_description | login_page_no |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 2        | test issue  | 1           | cover page       | 2014-01-30 | 2015-01-30 | sdssdg fsdf       | 20            |
| 3        | test issue1 | 4           | cover page1      | 2014-01-30 | 2015-01-30 | sdssdg fsdf       | 20            |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

in tbl_issue_log contain multiple records for same issue id. i want only one issue at a time
and this must latest updated time.

My query is this

```
SELECT 
    `tbl_issue_log`.`operation`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_ID`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_NAME`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`MAGAZINE_ID`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`COVER_PAGE_THUMB`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`FROM_DATE`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`TO_DATE`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`issue_description`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`login_page_no`
FROM
    `tbl_issue_log`
        LEFT JOIN
    `tbl_magazine_issue` ON tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_ID = tbl_issue_log.issue_id


WHERE
    (tbl_issue_log.mag_id = '1')
        AND (tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_STATUS = 3)
        AND (tbl_issue_log.updated_time > '2014-02-25 00:42:22')
GROUP BY tbl_issue_log.issue_id
ORDER BY tbl_issue_log updated_time DESC;
```

Here i got issue id based output . But not getting the latest updated timeed record.

If any one about this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
`tbl_issue_log`.`operation`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_ID`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_NAME`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`MAGAZINE_ID`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`COVER_PAGE_THUMB`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`FROM_DATE`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`TO_DATE`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`issue_description`,
`tbl_magazine_issue`.`login_page_no`
FROM
`tbl_issue_log`
    LEFT JOIN
`tbl_magazine_issue` ON tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_ID = tbl_issue_log.issue_id
WHERE
(tbl_issue_log.mag_id = '1')
    AND (tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_STATUS = 3)
    AND (tbl_issue_log.updated_time > '2014-02-25 00:42:22')
ORDER BY tbl_issue_log.updated_time DESC ) TEMP_TABLE
GROUP BY ISSUE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing order by clause as

```
ORDER BY tbl_issue_log.updated_time  DESC;
```

Edit ---
As you are grouping on issue_id, mysql will select first row that matches the issue_id. The order by runs later which essentially does not return what you are looking for. You may need to use a subquery approach for this.

```
select some_table.* FROM 
(
SELECT 
    MAX(tbl_issue_log.updated_time) AS updated_time,
    `tbl_issue_log`.`operation`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_ID`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`ISSUE_NAME`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`MAGAZINE_ID`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`COVER_PAGE_THUMB`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`FROM_DATE`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`TO_DATE`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`issue_description`,
    `tbl_magazine_issue`.`login_page_no`
FROM
    `tbl_issue_log`
        LEFT JOIN
    `tbl_magazine_issue` ON tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_ID = tbl_issue_log.issue_id


WHERE
    (tbl_issue_log.mag_id = '1')
        AND (tbl_magazine_issue.ISSUE_STATUS = 3)
        AND (tbl_issue_log.updated_time > '2014-02-25 00:42:22')
GROUP BY tbl_issue_log.issue_id
) some_table
ORDER BY some_table.updated_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a copying mistake. i got output but i can't latest updated issue details.